# Problems with Search

Tags: category, search

Im new to Joomla and trying to figure out how to use search.
I have three categories: French level 1, French level 2, French level 3.

When I do search for French level 1, all three categories come up in my search results. In addition to this problem, the results display with the category name at the top (rather than the article name).

Any help is appreciated! Thank you.

Comment: Your others category was enable?

Answer (score 1):

If you are using the default Search Component, you can't filter by categories, but
 we have some solutions:

You can use another search component, in joomla! you also have a
**Smart Search** 
Component, you can find this under:

**Components** > **Smart Search** and 
**Extensions** > **Modules** > **New** > **Smart Search**, you have some configuration in:
 
**System** > **Global Configuration** > **Smart Search**

In the front-end you can see something like the screenshot:
[image]

Also you can use some extensions like:

- [BT Smart Search](http://extensions.joomla.org/extensions/extension/search-a-indexing/site-search/bt-smart-search)
- [Universal Ajax Live Search](http://extensions.joomla.org/extensions/extension/search-a-indexing/site-search/universal-ajax-live-search)

Regards!